# Inserting a variable within a double quoted string

Tags: go

I have a beginner Golang question. I am coming at this with basic Python experience.

I am trying to workout how to insert a string variable, within a variable named body, which is used within an AMQP library further on in my program.

body expects a string value which is enclosed within double quotes. For example:

```
body := "This messages contains,variable1"
```

In my program I am creating a variable as an int64 data type and converting it to a string.

```
    ...
    TimeNow := currentEpochTime()     // Sets TimeNow to an int64 epoch timestamp
    variable1:= string(TimeNow)       // Converts TimeNow to a string
```

I am trying to insert variable1 after "This messages contains, -
and then enclose it with " - so that something like the below is passed to the AMQP library via the body variable.

```
    body := "Timestamp,1513011846048"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Go does not do this kind of string interpolation. Take a look at the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt) and [`template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) packages for potential solutions.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you - I seem to be trying to use a Python way of thinking on this which is getting me nowhere - I will check fmt and template for solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `fmt` package: `body := fmt.Sprintf("Timestamp,%d", TimeNow)`

The string() conversion converts an integer to a string, but not in the way you think.

See Effective Go for an [introduction to formatting and printing strings](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#printing).

Comment: Thank you Cerise, I seem to be stuck using a Python way of thinking on this - I will try using your suggestion (and also see Effective Go...) and come back to you...

Comment: Excellent - this works as needed and I now see where I was going wrong - thank you for your help!

Comment: fmt.Sprintf is very similar to Python's string format method: `body = "Timestamp,{:d}".format(TimeNow)`